# Compressed Textures in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, opengl-4

I have read that compressed textures are not readable and are not color render-able.
Though I have some idea of why its not allowed, can some one explain in little detail.

What exactly does it mean its not readable. I can not read from them in shader using say image Load etc? Or I cant even sample from them?

What does it mean its not render-able to? Is it because user is going to see all garbage anyway, so its not allowed.

I have not tried using compressed textures.

Answer (score 2):

Compressed textures are "readable", by most useful definitions of that term. You can read from them via samplers. However, you can't use `imageLoad` operations on them. Why? Because reading such memory is not a simple memory fetch. It involves fetching lots of memory and doing a decompression operation.

Compressed images are not color-renderable, which means they cannot be attached to an FBO and used as a render target. One might think the reason for this was obvious, but if you need it spelled out. Writing to a compressed image requires doing image compression on the fly. And most texture compression formats (or compressed formats of any kind) are not designed to easily deal with changing a few values. Not to mention, most compressed texture formats are lossy, so every time you do a decompress/write/recompress operation, you lose image fidelity.

Answer (score 1):

From the [OpenGL Wiki](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Format#Compressed_formats):

> Despite being color formats, compressed images are not color-renderable, for obvious reasons. Therefore, **attaching a compressed image to a framebuffer object will cause that FBO to be incomplete and thus unusable.** For similar reasons, no compressed formats can be used as the internal format of renderbuffers.

So "not color render-able" means that they can't be used in FBOs.

I'm not sure what "not readable" means; it may mean that you can't bind them to an FBO and read from the FBO (since you can't bind them to an FBO in the first place).

Comment: Yes, buy my question is why.

Comment: Probably because compressing them on the fly would be difficult, and may modify several pixels near each rendered primitive, which may break what you're trying to do with them.

Comment: I was thinking more on the lines like its possible, but the user will read/see all garbage texels, because its not a single RBBA texel anymore, instead compressed data of 1 or more texels. And since this leads to undesired results it is not supported.

Comment: So the question is "why did the spec explicitly disallow it rather than allowing it but making it completely useless?"

Comment: "Readable" might refer to reading them with `glGetTexImage()`.